# How to use server middleware to redefine routing in nuxt 3?

Tags: express, nuxt3

I get project on nuxt3 and I need to redefine router.

In `nuxt 2` I used `express` to do it

server/middleware/pages.js

```
const express = require('express')
const { Router } = require ('express')
const app = express ()
const router = Router()

router.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
   // do some logic
   next()
})

app.use(router)
module.exports = app
```

And thus I get the following routing behavior: depending on the URL, I can display either a nuxt page or an HTML page that is located in nuxt public directory.
But in `nuxt 3` I can't use express.
Help me to figure out the way to do it please.

My try number 1:

```
import { createApp, createRouter, fromNodeMiddleware } from 'h3';

const app = createApp();
const router = createRouter();


router.get('*', fromNodeMiddleware(async (req, res, next) => {
        //old logic
);
```

It doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution - `h3-express` library.

```
import { defineExpressHandler } from 'h3-express';
import express from 'express';

export default defineExpressHandler(express.Router().get('*', async (req, res, next) => {
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the documentation for Nuxt 3 regarding the `server/` directory. It no longer uses Express, it now uses Nitro instead. You can configure middleware with files in the `server/middleware/` directory [as stated in the docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/server#server-middleware).

Comment: Exactly! My question is about the way to use middleware in server directory wihtout express. I created the file /server/middleware/custom-pages.ts and it doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, I see. I misunderstood what you were trying to accomplish. Glad that you found a solution that works for you.